# How can I Auto Populate Magento Products ( 50K )

Tags: product, testing

I need to do some test and for my purpose I need a store with more that 50K products so samples data are not enough.

I wonder if there is any way to auto populate a magento store with fake products, even only simple products, what I really need is that the products are working in the front end and so:

1. assigned to a category ( any one )
2. enabled
3. are visible in catalog/search
4. have an url and a sku
5. have a random name/sku

because I need many product any direct SQL approach is welcome

Answer (score 3):

I've build 2 small scripts for myself a while back to do just that. The project is on [Github](https://github.com/sandermangel/magento-dummy-installers).

It's only simple products but the rest of the data is random. Images are pulled from a random image API so please take in consideration the amount of bandwidth 50K * ... images will use up. Might be smart do add a small sleep function in there to not overtask the network.

You can use it and if you make any improvements please fork it!

Comment: Ha. I saw this script and was just looking for it on github. +1. And about the images, I think it can be changed easily to take a random image from a local folder to avoid all that network issue. One question though. How lonk do you think It will take to call 50k times `$product->save()`.

Comment: thank you for the flash answer :) can you provide some basic instruction on how to use it ?

Comment: I'm getting this error "Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`MAGE_18EX`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`"

Comment: ok it need to set an existing  'attribute_set_id'

Comment: @Marius It is definitely a good question, on my system (SSD+8GBram+i5) about 1 sec x product so about 13 hours :( ( maybe I can dump the query and create an SQL version of the scritp ) –

Comment: @Marius yup, small disclaimer. 50K products shouldn't be done on a live environment ;) I'm actually working on a roadmap for this project, please leave a ticket on github and I'll look into it. (or contribute ;) )

Comment: @SanderMangel. Yeah. I figured that this is a script for developers. Nobody is going to generate 50k products to put on a live env. I was just curious on how long it will take.

Comment: @Marius 15 products normally takes me a few seconds. Like 6 or so.
oh wow.... yup it might run for a while

Comment: @Marius actually I'm looking into making sample data with 10K+ of products (all types) for benchmarking purposes. It'll work on direct queries tho

Comment: @SanderMangel. WOW. a sample data with up to 10k products would be a huge help for developers (and not only).

Answer (score 2):

**The Idea**
Since the import that magento has built in is much faster than `$product->save()` how about short-circuiting the import process?

**The approach**
I mean generate an array with 50k (or more) elements in the format that the import needs it. (not sure exactly what that is yet but I tried with one in the code below).
This should be easy enough, specially if you change a bit [the script recommended by @SanderMangel](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/17369/146).
Then you can insert it directly in the table `importexport_importdata`. That is where the data is stored when you press `Check file` in the import process.
You can insert it all at once but I think inserting chunks of it would work better.
After the insert is done trigger the import process.

**The code**

**Step 1. Build the array.**

```
$toImport = array();
$totalRows = 50000;
for ($i = 0;$i<$totalRows;$i++) {
    $data = array();
    $data['store'] = '';
    $data['_attribute_set'] = 'Default'; //or any attribute set name
    $data['_type'] = 'simple'; //insert only simple products
    $data['_product_websites'] = 'base'; //code for the base website
    //add some required data for the product like stock, tax class & ...
    $data['qty'] = 10;
    $data['min_qty'] = 0;
    $data['use_config_min_qty'] = 1;
    $data['is_qty_decimal'] = 0;
    $data['use_config_backorders'] = 1;
    $data['min_sale_qty'] = 1;
    $data['use_config_min_sale_qty'] = 1;
    $data['max_sale_qty'] = 10000;
    $data['use_config_max_sale_qty'] = 1;
    $data['is_in_stock'] = 1;
    $data['notify_stock_qty'] = 0;
    $data['use_config_notify_stock_qty'] = 1;
    $data['manage_stock'] = 1;
    $data['use_config_manage_stock'] = 1;
    $data['stock_status_changed_auto'] = 1;
    $data['use_config_enable_qty_inc'] = 1;
    $data['qty_increments'] = 1;
    $data['use_config_qty_increments'] = 1;
    $data['enable_qty_increments'] = 0;
    $data['is_decimal_divided'] = 0;
    $data['tax_class_id'] = 2;
    //set the visibility to catalog & search
    $data['visibility'] = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH;
    //set status as enabled
    $data['status'] = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED;
    $data['price'] = 9.99; //you can have a function that generates a random price
    $data['weight'] = 1.00; //you can have a function that generates a random weight (can use the same as for price even)
    //add product specific data
    $data['name'] = 'Some name'. $i; //you can generate a random string 
    $data['sku'] = 'some sku'.$i; //you can generate a random SKU
    $data['description'] = 'Some description'.$i; //you can generated a random description
    $data['short_description'] = 'Some short description'.$i; //you can generated a random short description 

    //continue with all the other required attributes if you have any
    //add categories
    $data['_category'] = '...';//not sure how this should look like
    //add images if needed. The images must be placed in `media/import`
    $data['image'] = '/path/to/image.png';
    $data['small_image'] = '/path/to/image.png';
    $data['thumbnail'] = '/path/to/image.png';
    $toImport[] = $data; //add the row to the import data

}
```

**Step 2. Insert the array in the `importexport_importdata` table**

```
//get an instance of the import model
$importModel = Mage::getResourceSingleton('importexport/import_data');
//clear all data that is already in the table for import
$importModel->cleanBunches();
//add your new data for import. `$toImport` is the array from step 1.
//you can even split the `$toImport` array into pieces of 2000 or something like that using `array_chunk`
$importModel->saveBunch('catalog_product', 'append', $toImport);
```

**Step 3. Trigger the import script**

```
Mage::getModel('importexport/import')->importSource();
```

I've used a similar script for an import and it seams to work, but I haven't used it on a live environment yet.

**The conclusion**
I'm not sure this will work for 50K products but it seams like a good place to start.
A reindex may be required when the import is done. Here you may hit an other problem. Indexing 50k products is not that fast.

Comment: yes I was thinking about using the import functionality as well ... I will give a try to your script, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

For M2 You could try this: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-perf-data.html

Running the command:

```
magento setup:perf:generate-fixtures /your/www/path/setup/performance-toolkit/profiles/ce/extra_large.xml
```